# Configure deployable file in gradle-cargo plugin

Tags: tomcat, gradle

I am trying to deploy a file which I download from repository. I will not be able to guess the version of file that is being downloaded before hand. So how do I refer this file explicitly?

Ex: The file I download from repository looks like `myfile-1.0.134243.war`. I wont be able to explicitly refer this file as `file = file("${buildDir}/repo/myfile-1.0.134243.war")` since I have no clue about the version.

This is how my configuration looks like now.

```
cargo {
   containerId = 'tomcat7x'
   port = 8080
   deployable {
       file = file("${buildDir}/repo").listFiles()[0]
       context = "${project.name}"
   }
   remote {
       hostname = "mytomcatserver"
       username = "${tomcat_username}"
       password = "${tomcat_password}"
       timeout = 6000
   }
}
```

Comment: What happens when your run this build script? Please provide the expected result as well as the actual result.

Comment: Hmm.. Interesting question. Ok. The current script what ever I have mentioned fetches the first file in repo directory and deploys it to container. But when there are more than one file in that directory, that is, when I have multiple versions of war file like `myfile-1.0.134243.war`, `myfile-1.0.31233.war`, `myfile-1.0.03425.war` etc.. The script fetches the file based on alpha order. Which is not always correct since I need to get the youngest file and not the file which is alphabetically least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a `doLast` task to the downloadtask which downloads the artitact from the repository. Inside that task I have renamed the downloaded file ang got rid off all the version information and then referenced the file as 
`file = file("${buildDir}/repo/${project.name}.war")` in the cargo configuration.

```
mydownloadtask.doLast{
   copy {
      from "${buildDir}/repo"
      into "${buildDir}/repo"
      rename (/[a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]+.[a-z]/, "${project.name}.war")
   }
}
```